# JDA - Converting "User" to "Member"

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

In order to remove roles from different users I use the following lines of code:

```
Member member = e.getMember();
Guild guild = member.getGuild();

for (Role role : guild.getRoles()) {
    System.out.println("getting em!");
    System.out.println(role.getId());
    if (role.getId().equals("496415978603675658")) {
        System.out.println("he has it, boss");
        guild.getController().removeSingleRoleFromMember(member, role)
                    .complete();
        guild.getController().addSingleRoleToMember(member, jda.getRoleById("496415995569766410"))
                    .complete();
    }
}
```

It works just fine, but the issue is that it only works with a Member object (`e.getMember`), and I can't figure out how do I retrieve the Member object otherwise. I have the other User stored as a User Object but I don't know how to convert him into a Member.

Answer (score 6):

```
Member member = guild.getMember(user);
```