# JDA - How to convert the "Member" Object to a "User" Object and not vice versa?

Tags: java, object, discord, discord-jda

I am trying to code a command to DM a mention person
!dm @JohnDoe, However, the mentioned user is a "Member", and DMing requires a "User".

```java
Member mentioned = event.getMessage().getMentionedMembers().get(0);
mentioned.openPrivateChannel().queue(DM -> { //Program Expected User not Member while "mentioned" is a Member. 
DM.sendMessage("You've been DMed.").queue(); };
```

Note : This isn't a duplicate of [JDA - Converting "User" to "Member"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52610379/jda-converting-user-to-member), I am converting from Member to User, not User to member.

I am trying to know how to convert from Member to User and not vice versa.
Also, If there's another way than converting please let me know.
Thanks,
Bedo

Comment: If I am not mistaken, isn't it `member.getUser();`?

Comment: That is your correct answer, yes thanks <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is:

```
User user = mentioned.getUser();
```

As described here: https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Member.html

**getUser()**: "The user wrapped by this Entity."